# Михайло Дмитрия Бальзаминов, сын её

Tags: ономастика

Почему в «Картинах московской жизни» А.Н. Островского главный герой  — Михайло *Дмитрия* (в лицах: «*Михайло Дмитрия Бальзаминов, сын её*»)? Почему не назван Дмитричем, подобно тому же Лукьяну Лукьянычу?

Answer (score 1):

Можно только предположить, что эта запись "заимствована" автором из церковной книги, в которой форма отчества записана по старинке, через притяжательную конструкцию "**чей сын**". Известно, что современная форма отчества (с суффиксами "-евич" и др.) первоначально (17 век) была даруемой отдельным людям привилегией, в то время как стандартной формой старого отчества было бы в нашем случае "Дмитриев (сын)". "Сын" в этой форме часто опускалось, поэтому я бы рассматривал вариант "Дмитрия" как *альтернативную притяжательность* (без образования притяжательного прилагательного), не вполне стандартную (даже по тем временам), но тоже отвечающую на вопрос "чей сын?" - "Дмитри**я** (сын)" вместо "Дмитри**ев** (сын)" (отсюда позже возникла и фамилия Дмитриев: 
 https://spbu.ru/sites/default/files/32-02-245.pdf ). 
 Прямого указания на альтернативный вариант в источниках не нашлось, а более подробное описание общей этимологии отчеств можно посмотреть здесь: https://forum.vgd.ru/post/29/21846/p1223204.htm

Comment: Спасибо за подробнейшую справку.